# Beginner question about using YQL to get html webpage in json

Tags: yql

I am trying to scrape a webpage using yql.  I thought outputing it as json would give me all the content as one object.  However if there are any html tags like < strong > that text is not included in "content".  Is there any way around this or should I just get it as xml and regex out the tags?

Answer (score 0):

It should return all elements from the page if your YQL statement  is **select * from html** where url="http://www.cnn.com".

```
select * from html where url="http://www.cnn.com".
```

Comment: thanks that's what I ended up doing.  I just thought there might be an easier way, like how you can use 'select content from html', but that's not working for me.